# ¿Cómo setear valores en una propiedad que es un array y es del tipo object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde debo serializar una clase en un Json, en esta clase existe una propiedad que es un arreglo y el tipo es object, fíjense este es la clase donde se encuentra el atributo **itemsField** y la propiedad **Items**.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Transform", Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class TransformType {

    private object[] itemsField;

    private string[] textField;

    private string algorithmField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("XPath", typeof(string))]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string[] Text {
        get {
            return this.textField;
        }
        set {
            this.textField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType="anyURI")]
    public string Algorithm {
        get {
            return this.algorithmField;
        }
        set {
            this.algorithmField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

luego escribo esto para asignar un valor pero me dice ERROR NO SE PUEDE INICIALIZAR EL TIPO OBJECT, ITEMS NO EXISTE EN EL CONTEXTO ACTUAL... ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

```
 Items = new object[1]
      {
       new object
            {
              Items[1]="",
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres inicializar dicha propiedad con un elemento del tipo cadena podrías hacer:

```
TransformType transformType = new TransformType();  
transformType.Items = new[] { "" };
```

[**DEMO**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t0CJTJ)

Answer (score 1):

Tendras que hacer referencia al namespace y clase de donde tengas tu object con using, para ello primero incluye tu object dentro de un namespace para apuntar a el:

```
namespace MyObject
{
    private object[] itemsField;

    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

}
```

y en tu script añades con using tu namespace:

using MyObject;

o bien lo llamas directamente desde tu declaración de la siguiente manera:

```
 Items = new MyObject.object[1]
  {
   new object
        {
          Items[1]="",
        }
  }
```

Comment: Hola JorelDraw...Edite mi pregunta para que puedas observar si tu respuesta no afecta otros aspecto del codigo

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera funciono

```
Transforms = new TransformType [1]
       {
         new TransformType
             {
             Items = new string[1] {Valor a Asignar},
             Text = new string [1]  { Valor a Asignar },
             Algorithm=Valor a Asignar                                    
              }
       }
```